# Is there a way to make sure a Facebook access token was generated for my application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

A web service I'm developing connects a user's account to their Facebook account through a API that passes a Facebook access token to the backend.  Is there some way to ensure that the access token that has been received belongs to my application?

Obviously, there will be errors later on if I try to use an access token from a different application to publish actions, for instance, but I'd rather catch this error case before associating the incorrect access token with a user's account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is just make an authenticated request to Facebook when you get their access token. Try and fetch their user info, maybe just their Facebook id, and verify the access token/Facebook id the user sent you is actually correct. You can make a request to the url:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token=...

to fetch just their id. I'd add this check to the registration process, since it's pretty important to get the pair correct.

Edited: To verify the app the access token belongs to, make a request to

https://graph.facebook.com/app?fields=id&access_token=

and it'll give you the app id of the token.

Comment: That is what I'm currently doing.  However, this does not catch the case where the access token is valid, but just not for my application.

For example, if I pass the token I get from the Graph API Explorer, the backend can still make a request to /me for the user's info, but not to the graph API method that publishes an action on somebody's timeline on behalf of my application.